# Declaring Global Variables in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to make a global array of custom objects that can be accessed throughout the app (AppDelegate, ViewController classes, TableViewController classes, etc). I have researched for a way to do it, but have not found an answer. I have tried making giving the array a public scope, but I get a complier warning which says `Declaring public variable from internal class` and when I try to access it in a different file, I get an error that says `Use of unresolved identifier 'arrayObjectives'`

How would I go about making that array globally accessible to all files in the application and where would I instantiate that array?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Properties.html) -

> Global variables are variables that are defined outside of any
> function, method, closure, or type context

So you can simply declare your variable at the top of any file straight after the `import` statements.

However, I would suggest you seriously reconsider. Generally globals aren't a good idea. You are better off with properties on a singleton or using dependency injection.

Your second question "where would I instantiate the array?" is part of the reason why globals are bad - their lifecycle isn't well defined in terms of your other objects. A singleton that is initialised on first use eliminates this issue.

Comment: If you use `private` as access modifier the global variable will just be global in the swift file you declare it... Which is quite useful in circumstances where you want a static variable (as `class`is not supported yet)

Comment: Globals are a completely natural and idiomatic part of Swift.

Comment: Sure, and C and a bunch of other languages. It still doesn't mean they are a good idea. Global constants are OK but global variables have many drawbacks in a multithreaded, object oriented, asynchronous environment.

Answer (score 13):

You can set global Array like this way :

```
import UIKit

var abc : String = String()
```

and you can access it in any other file like :

```
abc = "ABC"
```

Comment: Where would I set that? I know I can't do it in a function, but when I try to do it in a class, I get the complier warning mentioned above.

Comment: Exactly where they showed you - outside of any function or class

Comment: yes this way we can declare and access the global variables.. :)

Comment: hmm, i have defined a var outside the class in my firstVC but i am not able to get the values in another view? i have put var scannedVisitors = [Visitor]() in firstVC and in another in viewDidLoad() {   print("Visitors \(scannedVisitors)") but i get just Visitors [folder_name.Visitor, folder_name.Visitor, etc and not the data??

Answer (score 13):

Try making a new Swift file with this:

```
struct Constants {

  static let appName: String = "My App"

  struct Colors {

    static let colorTextStandard = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.3) //#000000

  }

  struct Data {

    static var myStrings = [String]()  // Yea, this is not a constant, but that's alright...

  }

}
```

You can then refer to those global constants (or you can make them variables) using:

```
Constants.appName
```

or

```
Constants.Colors.colorTextStandard
```

or

```
Constants.Data.myStrings = [stringOne, stringTwo]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did it...

```
class MessageViewCell {
    struct MessageViewCellHeightCache {
        static var cache: [String:CGFloat] = Dictionary<String, CGFloat>()
    }
}
```

And I accessed it as follows:

```
MessageViewCell.MessageViewCellHeightCache.cache["first"] = 12.0
```

Comment: This isn't a global. It is a singleton pattern

Comment: @Paulw11 - singleton is the best for these kind of scenarios

Comment: I agree - see my answer. This answer doesn't highlight that it is a singleton not a global.

Comment: In this example, why did you put the Dictionary in a Structure rather than instantiate the dictionary right away?

Comment: B/c class variables aren't supported in Swift yet. If you try doing this, you'll get a compilation error `class MessageViewCell { class var cache: [String:CGFloat] = Dictionary<String, CGFloat>() }`