# Global variable and optional binding in Swift

Tags: swift2, ios9, optional-variables

I have some quite simple doubt regarding optional binding,global variable & wrapping and unwrapping . Since I am new to SWIFT, its very important to understand the tits & bits of their concepts.

1) In Swift if I declare a global variable, I have 2 options either to make it optional or non optional, so let I am having 2-4 or more optional variables . So is it advisable to optional bind all those variables in

```
viewDidLoad() method// so that I could use them without any problem of unwrapping and fatal error in my program.
```

2) Let me make myself more clear by the following example- I have 2 VC in my project VC1 & VC2 . VC2 has a text field in which user enters some value and displays it in a tabelview in VC1.

In Vc1

```
var namevc1 = NSMutableArray?//holds the input of textfield to be passed from VC2.
```

As you can see, my VC1 is the first view controller that loads when my project runs and I am using an optional variable to populate my tabke vuew that is

```
'arr'
```

So when the app runs for the first time its empty . So it might cause a fatal error while using its value in the code. So what is its solution whether to unbind it in the

```
viewDidLoad()
```

method or in all total declare an empty NSMutable array type in place of optional type .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should avoid "global variables". For communication between controllers, use delegates.

Comment: @dfri If i want to pass via prepareForSegue(),I would obviously go for global variable right.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the concept of global variables in Swift. 1. If you have a global variable, you won't have to "pass" it between any views/methods/classes etc, because the variable is defined at global scope (accessible everywhere). 2. Generally global variables is not a good idea, and something that you want to avoid. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195262/swift-how-to-create-a-global-variable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601163/declaring-global-variables-in-swift

Comment: @dfri sorry for being late.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll start by repeating the my comment from above.

Possibly you've misunderstanding the concept of global variables in Swift.

1. If you have a global variable, you won't have to "pass" it between any views/methods/classes etc, because the variable is defined at global scope (accessible everywhere).
2. Generally global variables is not a good idea, and something that you want to avoid.

Regarding the matter of global variables and swift, you really should include *singletons* into the discussion. See e.g. the following existing SO thread(s):

- [Any reason not use use a singleton "variable" in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660471/any-reason-not-use-use-a-singleton-variable-in-swift)
- ([How to create a global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195262/swift-how-to-create-a-global-variable))
- ([Declaring Global Variables in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601163/declaring-global-variables-in-swift))

---

**Communication between TableViewController and ViewController by means of segues (prepare for & unwind segues)**

*(This answer ended up being very and probably a bit too thorough, as I didn't know in detail what your current tableview/viewcontroller program state looks like. Sorry for the lengthy answer and any inconvenience it might bring to readers of it)*.

Now, lets leave global variables and discuss one (among other) viable options for the communication between the two controllers in your example. From your question, I'll summarize your example as follows

- ***VC1***: storyboard entry point, a `UITableViewController` consisting of `UITableViewCell`s, where, in these cells, you display some text, say, via instances of `UILabel`.
- ***VC2***: a `UIViewController`, accessible from the cells of VC1, containing an `UITextField` instance. When user enters text into this text field, your want the text to be displayed in the associated *cell* in VC2 (associated in the sense that it was the cell in VC1 that was used to access VC2).

We'll associate VC1 and VC2 with (cocoa touch) classes `TableViewController` (*TableViewController.swift*) and `ViewController` (*ViewController.swift*), respectively. The cells in the table view controller will be associated with (cocoa touch) class `TableViewCell` (*TableViewCell.swift*). Details for these classes follow below.

For this simple example, note that we will not embed VC1 into a navigation controller (which is otherwise appropriate for table view -> view navigation).

We'll start in the storyboard, adding objects (drag-and-drop from object library) for a `Table View Controller` and a `View Controller`. The table view container will also, automatically, contain, in its `Table View`, a `TableViewCell`. Continuing in the storyboard:

- Add a `UILabel` object to the `TableViewCell` container in the `Table View Controller` (align it as you wish)
- In the `View Controller`, add a `Text Field` object and a `Button` object (align them as you wish).
- Set the entry point to the `Table View Controller`.
- Thereafter Ctrl-drag a 'Show' segue from the `TableViewCell` to the `View Controller`.
- Select the `Show` segue and, from the Attributes inspector, enter an identifier for it, say, *ShowDetail*.
- Finally, with the `TableViewCell` selected, (as above; from the attribute inspector), enter an identifier for the cell. Here, we'll use simply use identifier *TableViewCell*.

We now leave the storyboard for now and implement three classes, associated with the `Table View Controller`, the `View Controller` and the formers' `TableViewCell`.

We start with the `Table View Controller`, and implement our `UITableViewController` sub-class. Note that here, instead of using an `NSMutableArray` to hold the texts of the `UITextLabel` in each cell, we'll simply use a `String` array.

```
// TableViewController.swift
Import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // Properties
    var userTextLabels = [String]()
    var numberOfCells: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        numberOfCells = loadSampleTextLabels() // Load sample labels.
    }

    func loadSampleTextLabels() -> Int {
        userTextLabels += ["Label #1", "Label #2", "Label #3"]
        return userTextLabels.count
    }

    // func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) ...
    // func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ...

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = ("TableViewCell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        // Text for current cell
        let cellText = userTextLabels[indexPath.row]
        cell.userSuppliedTextLabel.text = cellText

        return cell
    }

    // ... communication?
}
```

Where the two commented out methods are standard methods used in any `UITableViewController`, for number of sections (e.g. `return 1`) and cells (e.g. `return (numberOfCells ?? 0)`) in the table, respectively. I'll leave fixing these to you.

Now, we associate the `TableViewCell` object(s) in the table view with instances of a subclass to `UITableViewCell`. Here, we'll use a very simple class for our cells; each cell just containing a single `UILabel` instance (created via storyboard Ctrl-drag as an `@IBOutlet` from the `UILabel` in the table view cells).

```
// TableViewCell.swift
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var userSuppliedTextLabel: UILabel!
        // Ctrl-drag from UILabel (in TableViewCell) in storyboard

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Finally, for the view controller that is accessed from the table view cells: use a single `@IBOutlet` to the `UITextField` used for user text input, and handle events in this text field using the pre-existing `UITextFieldDelegate`. E.g.:

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var userSuppliedText: UITextField!
        // Ctrl-drag from storyboard...
    var cellText: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userSuppliedText.text = cellText ?? "..."

        // Handle the user input in the text field through delegate callbacks
        userSuppliedText.delegate = self
    }

    // UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // User finished typing (hit return): hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        cellText = textField.text
    }

}
```

We've also declared a string property (`cellText`) here, that will as act as container for communication between VC1 and VC2.

We return to the storyboard and---from the Identity inspector---associate the three storyboard objects (`Table View Controller`, `View Controller`, `TableViewCell`) with their associated classes that we've just written above.

We're now almost at our goal; it only remains to specify how to communicate between the two controllers.

We'll begin with communication *from* VC1 *to* VC2. In your comment above, you were on the right track (for this specific solution, anyway) by looking at the `prepareForSegue(...)` method. In the class for the `Table View Controller`, we add the following method:

```
// ... add to TableViewController.swift
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        if let selectedCell = sender as? TableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedCell)!
            let currentTextInCell = userTextLabels[indexPath.row]
            viewController.cellText = currentTextInCell // <-- note this
        }
    }
}
```

Hence, for VC1->VC2 communication, we can (in this example) bring whatever existing text that is currently occupying the `UILabel` in the sender cell (as is specified by the String array `userTextLabels`). Look at the `viewDidLoad(...)` method in the *ViewController.swift* to see how this value is passed from VC1 and set as default text in the `UITextField` in VC2.

Now, for communication VC2->VC1, which was the specific communication direction you were asking about, add another method (programmatically), again to *TableViewController.swift*:

```
// ... add to TableViewController.swift
@IBAction func unwindToTableView(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? ViewController, 
        text = sourceViewController.cellText {
            // ^ note 2nd clause of if let statement above    
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update cell text
            userTextLabels[selectedIndexPath.row] = text
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we define an unwind action that, when triggered, retrieves the `cellText` property of the view controller that was the source of the segue, i.e., in our case, the instance of `ViewController`. But how do we trigger this action?

Return to the storyboard and the `View Controller`. Note the three little icons in the top of the `View Controller` object, more specifically, the right-most of these, named `Exit`. Ctrl-drag an action from your `Button` to the `Exit` icon, and select the `unwindToTableView` Action Segue. When you click your button the view controller, the view unwind (exit) and land at the `unwindToTableView` method in the `TableViewController`.

The resulting app should look something like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

This was way longer than I had expected, but once you get started writing... Anyway, the method above uses, naturally, no global variables, but make use of references to future (`prepareForSegue`) or historic (`unwindToTableView`) views to get (generally from current or historic view) or set (generally in current of future view) values by using these references (to future/historic view).

Apple has their own very thorough tutorial on an example app in the tableviewcontroller/viewcontroller context that I would recommend going over. I found it very valuable myself when I started coding Swift.

[Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html)