# how can i get the text Value of a textView which is inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

i have a UITableView which has multiple Prototype cells (with different identifiers ) and i have a separate class for my Cells ! this is how i've created my TableViewController :-

```
import UIKit
class PostTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {   
var postArray = [["Sean Paul","Got To Love You"],["California","21 January 2018"],["Martin Garrix"]]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    print(postArray[section].count)
    return  postArray[section].count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0{

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("titleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
        MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell            
    }        
    if indexPath.section == 0 &&  indexPath.row == 1 {
         cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
        MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell            
        }
    if indexPath.section == 1 &&  indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("locationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
        MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell
    }
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("timeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
        MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell
    }
    if  indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("recipientCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
        MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell
    }        
    return cell
  }
@IBAction func btnActionPost(sender: AnyObject) {        
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
   print( tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text) // here i tried to get the text of first cell but text is not in the cell's label it is inside the TextView which is inside UItableViewCell
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
  }
  }
```

and this is how i've created my TableViewCellController:-

```
  import UIKit

 class MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

// @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView?
@IBOutlet var titleTxtField: UITextField!    
@IBOutlet var locationTxtField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var timeTxtField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var recipientTxtField: UITextField!
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

/// Custom setter so we can initialise the height of the text view
var textString: String {
    get {
        return textView?.text ?? ""
    }
    set {
        if let textView = textView {
            textView.text = newValue

            textViewDidChange(textView)
        }
    }
    }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    // Disable scrolling inside the text view so we enlarge to fitted size
    textView?.scrollEnabled = false
    textView?.delegate = self
   }

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        textView?.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        textView?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
 }

    extension MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell: UITextViewDelegate {
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    let size = textView.bounds.size
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.max))

    // Resize the cell only when cell's size is changed
    if size.height != newSize.height {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        tableView?.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

        if let thisIndexPath = tableView?.indexPathForCell(self) {
            tableView?.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(thisIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
}

extension UITableViewCell {
    /// Search up the view hierarchy of the table view cell to find the containing table view
   var tableView: UITableView? {
    get {
        var table: UIView? = superview
        while !(table is UITableView) && table != nil {
            table = table?.superview
        }

        return table as? UITableView
    }
  }
 }
```

i tried this for getting the text from the cell:- but its not the proper approach

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
   print( tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text) // here i tried to get the text of first cell but text is not in the cell's label it is inside the TextView which is inside UItableViewCell

tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

if anybody knows then please guide  me it will be very helpful for me  :)

Comment: I recently described in detail the communication between a custom `UITableViewCell`, a `UITableViewController` and a `UIViewController`, possibly it can help you to cover that and apply to your case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247239/global-variable-and-optional-binding-in-swift/34275632#34275632

Comment: @dfri thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)` returns a `UITableViewCell?` which has a `textLabel` property, which itself is a UILabel — but you never assign anything to the textLabel on the UITableViewCell; you assign to your custom `textView` property.

Try this instead:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
let multilineCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? MultiLineTextInputTableViewCell // we cast here so that you can access your custom property.
print(multilineCell?.textView.text)
```

This way you are operating on your custom cell's TextView.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4 -**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
print(cell.textView.text)
```