# Making a randomizer picking words from text field (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make app that takes info from the two text fields and randomly selects one of the sentences and places it in a label on another view controller. I'm a student in the Mobile Apps 1 class so I'm new to this. If you could explain it as much as possible it will be greatly appreciated. Happy new year!

My code:

```
class twoIdeasViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var twoIdeaContinueButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var twoIdea2TextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var twoIdea1TextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Enter Ideas"
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let twoIdea1:String = twoIdea1TextField.text!
        let twoIdea2:String = twoIdea2TextField.text!
        return true
    }

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, Object: AnyObject?){
        let twoIdeaFinal = segue.destinationViewController as! twoFinalViewController
        twoIdeaFinal.twoIdea = //the variable that will contain the randomizer    
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what you have tried and what is not working. Also, check the "Related" section to the right, for questions that are similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `arc4random_uniform()` to generate a random number that controls which of the two text fields you wish to extract and send text from. Also, you seem to need to fix up your `prepateForSegue` method: you need to match the segue identifier with the identifier of your 2nd view controller (set in attributes inspector while selecting this other view controller in your storyboard).

```
@IBOutlet weak var twoIdea2TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var twoIdea1TextField: UITextField!

// ...

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    /* Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
       Pass the randomly chosen text view text to the UILabel of the
       new view controller. */

    /* Here: you need to match with the identifier of your
       VC 'twoFinalViewController' (set in attributes inspector) */
    if segue.identifier == "twoFinalVC" {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController

        let random = arc4random_uniform(2)
        viewController.twoFinalLabel.text = (random == 0) ? (twoIdea1TextField.text ?? "") : (twoIdea2TextField.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

For a detailed description covering segue communication between two view controllers (`UITableViewController` and `UIViewController`), see the following thread

- [Global variable and optional binding in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247239/global-variable-and-optional-binding-in-swift/34275632#34275632)

Comment: text doesn't pop up in my label when I run it. It's something with my second viewcontroller probably :    class twoFinalViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var twoIdea = String()

    @IBOutlet weak var twoFinalLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        twoFinalLabel.text = "\(twoIdea)"


    }
    
}

Comment: @DDoe Please add this additional code into your question, not these comments.

Comment: @DDoe see if the updated answer fixes it for you. Note that you need to match the `segue.identifier` with the corresponding identifier you've entered in the Attributes inspector for the target view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
func getRandomString() -> String
{
    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1

    switch randomNumber
    {
        case 1:
            return twoIdea1TextField.text!
        case 2:
            return twoIdea2TextField.text!
        default:
            return ""
    }
}
```

I have no time, but I think that with an enum is simpler than what I did.

Comment: How would i send this through the segue? Do I send the function getRandomString through so it would be: twoIdeaFinal.twoIdea = getRandomString

Comment: It should be 'twoIdeaFinal.twoIdea = self.getRandomString()'

Comment: The code works, but it the information doesn't appear in the label. The label is just blank, Is there something wrong with the second viewcontroller code? : 

class twoFinalViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var twoFinalLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        twoFinalLabel.text = "\(twoRandom)"


    }
    var twoRandom = String()
}

Comment: What's wrong is the way you are setting the label value. If you debug your code, into viewDidLoad you haven't yet the randomString...

Comment: What do I have to do to the label i set. @LucaD

Comment: @dfri the text doesn't show still. The label just disappears when I run the app.